# Firebase Auth Listener Not Fired On User Change

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I am using [Xamarin.Firebase.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebase-auth) . In the registration activity of my app, I want to check to make sure that the username has not already been taken. I need to check the usernames in the database. Since this is the registration, the user is not yet authenticated and does not have access to the database. I allow for Anonymous authentication for this portion of the app.

After the username is cleared for use, I create the new user with `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` and I need my AuthState listener to be fired once that is complete. The issue is, the listener does not seem to fire when the user is changed from anonymous to the created user.

Here is my current AuthStateListener:

```
FirebaseAuth.Instance.AuthState += (sender, e) =>
        {
            FirebaseUser oUser = e?.Auth?.CurrentUser;

            if (oUser != null && !oUser.IsEmailVerified && !oUser.IsAnonymous)
            {
                //They were successfully created, send the verification email
                if (oUser.SendEmailVerification().IsSuccessful)
                {
                    UserProfileChangeRequest oProfile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                                    .SetDisplayName(txtName.Text).Build();

                    oUser.UpdateProfile(oProfile);

                    //Add the user information to the database
                    Users oUserToSave = new Users();
                    oUserToSave.displayname = txtName.Text;
                    oUserToSave.email = txtEmail.Text;
                    oUserToSave.prestige = 1;
                    oUserToSave.username = sUsername;


                    //It worked, they need to verify their email address
                    //redirect them to the verification page
                    Intent oVerifyIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(VerificationActivity));
                    StartActivity(oVerifyIntent);
                    FirebaseAuth.Instance.AuthState += null;
                    Finish();
                }
            }
            else if (oUser != null && oUser.IsAnonymous && allowAuthChange)
            {
                //Need to validate their registration
                ValidateRegistration();
            }
        };
```

How can I make sure that the listener is called when `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` completes? The documentation for Firebase states that the listener should be fired in these instances:

> - Right after the listener has been registered
> - When a user is signed in
> - When the current user is signed out
> - When the current user changes

Does the switch from an anonymous user to a newly created one not count as a user change?

Comment: Have you read the [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) document ? As I understand, you need use the `linkWithCredential` method instead of the "normal" `signInWith` flow.

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer? This was a good solution and fired the AuthState listener as I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the firebase document :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

You need use the `linkWithCredential` method instead of the "normal" signInWith flow.